# Reactjs-Redux: Even after user is logged in, mapStateToProps returns user is authenticated as false at first, then true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have implemented redux with reactjs, all my authentication is in place.

So whenever a user authenticates, a token is stored within the redux store,

I have implemented mapStateToProps function with my app component to map a prop isAuthenticated to true if a token is available.

I have also implemented mapDispatchToProps function to dispatch an action which checks user auth status, this action is dispatched on componentDidMount.

The problem is even after the user is authenticated, the prop 'isAuthenticated' initially returns false then true.

**Here is the code:**

```
class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAuthStatus();
  }

  render() {
    //console.log(this.props);

    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar {...this.props} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={ LoginForm } />
          <Route path="/register" component={ RegistrationForm } />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.token !== null,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getAuthStatus: () => { dispatch(actions.checkAuthStatus()) },
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**code for actions**

```
export const authSuccess = (token) => {
    return {
        type: 'AUTH_SUCCESS',
        token: token
    }
}

export const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    return {
        type: 'AUTH_LOGOUT'
    }
}


export const checkAuthStatus = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token === undefined) {
            dispatch(logout());
        } else {           
                dispatch(authSuccess(token));         
        }
}
```

**Code for reducers:**

```
const initialState = {
    token: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false
}

export const authSuccess = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {
        token: action.token,
        error: null,
        loading: false
    })
}

export const authLogout = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {
        token: null,
    })    
}

const rootReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'AUTH_SUCCESS': return authReducers.authSuccess(state, action);
        case 'AUTH_LOGOUT': return authReducers.authLogout(state, action);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**The Index File:**

```
const storeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store = createStore(rootReducer, storeEnhancer(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

const app = (
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <App />
    </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: add actions and reducer code too

Comment: How are you registering the reducers?

Comment: Are your referring to the initial load of your app?

Comment: Yes, i am referring to the initial load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you include the token in the initial state, you're going to see token as false until checkAuthStatus is fired, which in your case is componentDidMount. You could set token to the localStorage value in the initial state.